# Databbase file structure on disk

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, sqlite

I'm an interested in the fundamentals of databases for a project that I am currently working on. Specifically the physical storage on disk and how rows and indexes are stored in a file. For the most part I understand the SQLite data file layout.

I cannot seem to find the insights on how PostgreSQL and SQL Server store there data on disk and how the file structure is built up. Just to be clear, I am looking for the technical description on how databases store there data on disk, specifically the file layout.

Does anyone know where to find more information about this topic?

Comment: You will not find any information on this except for Open Source databases. The manufactures of databases keep their layout of files secret. For Open Source databases you can consult the source code itself if it is not documented well.

Comment: That is the problem, I really want to have some sort of documentation where is explains _how_ and _why_ certain things are happening. You can not subtract that data form source.

Comment: Actually he will. The sql server file format is fully described, at least in some books. You an start for example at http://www.pythian.com/blog/analyzing-sql-server-data-file-anatomy/

Comment: That is certainly useful. Is there something like it for PostgreSQL?

Comment: PostgreSQL is open source!

Comment: Try this for PostgreSQL http://www.slideshare.net/PostgresOpen/inside-shmem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested:
- http://www.slideshare.net/PostgresOpen/inside-shmem
- http://www.pythian.com/blog/analyzing-sql-server-data-file-anatomy/
And will do it for now